# How can i know how much free memory i have in a linux machine?

Tags: linux

When i use:

```
  cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemFree 


  htop: Mem
```

I get different free memory results.

I want to run a memory consuming process. What is the number of all of the above that is relevant to me?

Comment: your command is correct!! what us ouput of cat /proc/meminfo

Answer (score 2):

Simply try **free -m** which give available memory in MB. You can also try **vmstat** -s which gives free memory in KB.

Comment: This does not address my question.